# How to connect web3.js 1.3.4 to MetaMask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am trying to connect to MetaMask and I have read their docs about the breaking changes and everything. From what I understand, they are not injecting web3 into window.web3 but instead are using window.ethereum. However, I am using this but when I try to run `web3.eth.getAccounts` my code returns an error saying that `eth` is not defined, and furthermore that "metamask no longer injects web3". But I thought that I changed this correctly to use window.ethereum?

Here is my code, first I call this function and then set `window.web3` to the web3 provider.

```
  async loadWeb3() {
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
      // Modern dapp browsers
      if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        // legacy dapp browsers
      } else if (window.web3) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
      }
    });
  }
```

After that, I use the provider object and call eth.getAccounts():

```
  async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = window.web3;
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  }
```

But I get an error saying that "cannot read property getAccounts of undefined".

Comment: After some testing, I realized that window.web3 becomes a Proxy object whenever I access it outside of where I initially created a new Web3 object. This proxy object has some different characteristics, notably, eth is not defined on it directly, which is why there is an error. Any reason why this proxy object is created and how to work with it?

Comment: The block were installed because i own the web and they are scared of me tgere is no reason to be scared unless you do not conceed the world wide web and all of the data az ai u&i as we are 1

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I got:

> MetaMask no longer injects web3. For details, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3

I followed the link and was able to resolve the issue by changing `window.web3.<function>` to `window.ethereum.request({method: "<equivalent_function_with_different_name>"})`

So, concretely, I changed `await web3.eth.getAccounts();` to `await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });`

---

I am myself a beginner, thus, I'm not really sure if this is relevant, but I have an `initWeb3` function which seems to resemble your `loadWeb3` function. There, I executed the following (note the `eth_requestAccounts` part):

```
initWeb3: async function() {
    App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("User denied account access.")
    }

    return App.initContract();
},
```